# javaScript object doesn't keep key order giving from php

Tags: javascript, php, object

I have an array that I use `json_encode` on which looks like this in `PHP`

```
Array
    (
        [4] => Array
            (
                [numberof] => 60
                [date] => 4
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [numberof] => 3
                [date] => 3
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [numberof] => 6
                [date] => 2
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [numberof] => 5
                [date] => 1
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [numberof] => 1
                [date] => 12
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [numberof] => 0
                [date] => 11
            )

    )
```

However, when accessing via `javaScript`the order will be the following

```
{
      "1":{"numberof":5,"date":"1"},
      "2":{"numberof":6,"date":"2"},
      "3":{"numberof":3,"date":"3"},
      "4":{"numberof":60,"date":"4"},
      "11":{"numberof":0,"date":"11"},
      "12":{"numberof":1,"date":"12"}
 }
```

How can I keep the order that was set in PHP.

Comment: The hash map doesn't have any order. If you need to maintain order - store it in an array.

Comment: That order *is* set in PHP - look at the array keys.

Comment: am i stupid or is the order exactly the same in js ?

Comment: @larsAnders ha guys, the order in php is 4,3,2,1,12,11 the order in JS is 1,2,3,4,11,12. I need it to keep the same order from php

Comment: @zerkms I assume then, there is no way to keep the hash map?

Comment: If you want to have same order, you can add an index property with the order you want and then order by index

Comment: wtf then use assoative arrays with the number as string maybe

Comment: @Jamie Hutber: there is no way to guarantee the order in a hash map because it doesn't maintain order by definition.

Comment: @juvian Care to elaborate... stuck in the mud atm :)

Comment: How are you generating the array? You could probably assign order during the generation process...

Comment: @johnSmith johny boy, you're a genius. Indeed, just use strings and it'll keep the order. Anybody fancy adding the answer with a little explin for people who might not know why :/?

Comment: @JamieHutber That answer is only partially correct and may cause you more issues in the future. It sets the order in the JSON string to what you want, but once you parse it to a Javascript object the order is by definition undefined. Never rely on the order of an object's keys in Javascript. If you do you have buggy code, which could break at random.

Comment: If you want order, you should use an array rather than an object: `[{"key": 4, "numberof": 60, "date": 4}, ...]`

Comment: Thanks @Paulpro Luckily I'm not replying on it, but for the graph its better to have it in order ;) Using a string certainly does do the trick for me. I chagned the numbers to the string value of the month rather than the digits

Comment: That way the order is guaranteed and you still have all the same data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript objects are not ordered.

[ECMA 5.1 section 4.3.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.3) (Doesn't guarantee the order)

> An object is a collection of properties and has a single prototype
>   object. The prototype may be the null value.

[ECMA 3rd Edition section 4.3.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) (Explicitly says it is not ordered)

> An object is a member of the type Object. It is an **unordered**
>   collection of properties each of which contains a primitive value,
>   object, or function. A function stored in a property of an object is
>   called a method.

Even with a JavaScript *"associative array"* (which basically is a collection of named properties in the object) you can't guarantee the order.

Comment: Correct, I have had issues with this as well. The only way you can actually order items, is by sorting the keys based on values (associative).

Comment: Ye, which goes against anything I want ;0

Answer (score 1):

i´m a genius and you should use an so called associative array
where the keys are not numbers but strings

```
//so instead of

   [4] => Array
        (
            [numberof] => 60
            [date] => 4
        )

//make it 

   ["4"] => Array
        (
            [numberof] => 60
            [date] => 4
        )
```

and it might keep order