# How to sort object by numeric key value

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object that looks like this:

```
a = {10: 961, 11: 1418, 12: 1526, 13: 1652, 14: 1482, 15: 1581, 16: 1594, 17: 1201, 18: 816, 19: 994, 20: 455, 21: 910, 22: 1181, 23: 713, 00: 296, 01: 144, 02: 100, 03: 56, 04: 22}
```

How can I rearrange the order of the entries so it looks like

```
b = {00: 296, 01: 144, 02: 100, 03: 56, 04: 22, ...}
```

Not sure if this is relevant but I derive this object from a larger JSON object and need to sort it in order to display the data on a chart.

Comment: You can't sort objects.

Comment: @Teemu You can, to an extent, in some circumstances, including this one

Comment: @CertainPerformance No, you can't _sort_ objects (in the meaning of how arrays are sorted). That is different from keeping a specific order of the keys. You can iterate an object in a certain order, though.

Comment: @Teemu - Which is all you're doing with a "sorted" JavaScript (standard) array as well.

Comment: if you want to iterate through the object keys in a sorted way use `for(key of object.keys().sort())`

Comment: You're showing the key `00` (not `"00"`). Are you setting that key as a number? If so, the resulting key is `"0"` (not `"00"`), because object properties are always strings or Symbols. Or are you setting it as a string?

Answer (score 0):

Properties to objects are ordered by integer values first and then by the string keys in order of their addition to the object. Therefore it IS possible to order the properties by creating a new object from your object.

```
a = {10: 961, 11: 1418, 12: 1526, 13: 1652, 14: 1482, 15: 1581, 16: 1594, 17: 1201, 18: 816, 19: 994, 20: 455, 21: 910, 22: 1181, 23: 713, 00: 296, 01: 144, 02: 100, 03: 56, 04: 22};

b = {};
Object.keys(a).sort((a,b) => { return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b);}).forEach((x) => {
b[x] = a[x];});
console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you still need this four years after asking about it but - the short answer is that [you can't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23230845/6133426), as @Teemu mentioned in the comments.

What you can do (but it *might* not work for you if you specifically need a JSON to work with) is to use [maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). The following example uses strings for your keys, since your setup has keys like `00`, or `01`.

```js
// get all keys with desired value
function getKeys(obj,val) {
    let result = [];
    for(const key in obj) {
        if(obj[key] === val) {
            result.push(key);
        }
    }

    return result.sort();
}

let a = {"10": 961, "11": 1418, "12": 1526, "13": 1652, "14": 1482, "15": 1581, "16": 1594, "17": 1201, "18": 816, "19": 994, "20": 455, "21": 910, "22": 1181, "23": 713, "00": 296, "01": 144, "02": 100, "03": 56, "04": 22};
let b = new Map();
let vals = [];

// extract the values
for(let key in a) {
    if(vals.indexOf(a[key]) < 0) {
        vals.push(a[key]);
    }
}

// sort values descendingly
vals.sort(function(val1,val2){
    return val2 - val1;
});

// fill the resulting map with keys sorted by value
// if one value is attributed to more than one key
// sort those keys ascendingly
vals.forEach(function(val) {
    let keysWithVal = getKeys(a,val);

    keysWithVal.forEach(function(key) {
        b.set(key,val);
    });
});

b.forEach(function(mVal,mKey) {
    console.log(mKey,mVal);
});
```